# F#: currying differences between functions and static members

Tags: f#, currying

Can please someone explain this to me:

```
type IItem = interface end
type Item = {i:int} interface IItem

type Fail = static member foo (s:string) = fun (x:IItem) -> ""
let foo = fun (s:string) -> fun (x:IItem) -> ""

let works = {i=1} |> foo ""
let fails = {i=1} |> Fail.foo ""
```

Why does the currying with the static member function not work?
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with .net 4.5.2 if that matters.

Comment: to be honest - the better question is: why does `works` work - because both want a `IItem` while you give them a `Item` (F# usually don't do implicit casts) - and I guess that's your answer - the first one does the implicit cast while the second one does not

Comment: btw: you get `fail` to *work*  with `let fails = ({i=1} :> IItem) |> Fail.foo ""`

Comment: PS: so does `type Fail = static member foo (s:string) (x:IItem) = ""
` - I think it's an edge case with the static members and the lambda (you can see it in the signatures: `string -> (IItem -> string)` vs `string -> IItem -> string` **which makes no sense** from a *theoretical* point of view - I'm sure Tomas or some other with deep specification knowledge will come around and tell us exactly why ;)

Comment: I think it might be because the `static member` will not always be a `FSharpFunc` ... but here I start guessing - it's an interesting question though and I wish I had more time right now to do some research

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to F# usually don't do implicit casts - that is new to me (as I'm new to F#)!

Comment: Implicit subtyping doesn't play well with type inference, plus in my expenience, it actually _hurts_ more than helps, even in C#. But you _can_ design your functions to feel as if implicit casting happens by making them generic and applying constraints: `let foo<'t when 't :> IItem> (i: 't) = ...`, or shortened syntax for same thing: `let foo (i: #IItem) = ...`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin `foo` here works as is - it's the unusual written `foo` static member that works differently (although on first glance it looks very similar) - I will not call it a *bug* but IMO it's not far from it (there should be no semantic difference between a `string -> IItem -> string` and a `string -> (IItem -> string)` - indeed you usually teach people that these are *the same*)

Comment: §14.4.2 of the [spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf), _Implicit Insertion of Flexibility for Uses of Functions and Members_, seems relevant, but it doesn't note the different treatment of functions and methods.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a difference between static members and functions - it's a bit more subtle.  Here's another repro:

```
type T =
    static member A () (o:obj) = ()
    static member B () = fun (o:obj) -> ()

T.A () 1 // ok
T.B () 1 // huh?
```

Note that the signatures of `T.A` and `T.B` are different (this is actually covered in section 11.2.1.1 of the spec):

```
type T =
  class
    static member A : unit -> o:obj -> unit
    static member B : unit -> (obj -> unit)
  end
```

This is a distinction that is usually unimportant, but basically it means that at a .NET representation level `A` is compiled to a method with two arguments (even though it looks curried in F#) while `B` is compiled to a method with a single argument which returns an F# function.  This difference is ultimately what causes the behavior you're seeing.